# symfony2.3 bad credentials in production mode OVH

Tags: symfony, php-5.4, ovh

i know the question is repeated but the scenario that i'm going to describe is (very) strange :

1. register a new user
2. update the profile
3. reconnect but bad credentials

   - the bundle works normally in dev mode, but stack in prod mode

using fosuser_bundle

```
security:
    encoders:
        "Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User":
            algorithm: sha512
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 1


firewalls : 
        main:
            pattern:      .*
            context:        user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                csrf_provider:   form.csrf_provider
                use_referer: true
```

all was perfectly working a month ago
Please let me help if you need some codes, Thanks

Comment: Why do you have two encoders?

Comment: i deleted this "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User": plaintext but same problem !

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, i was wondering why it works on dev mode and not in prod mode ? the solution was with the configuration of ovh in **.ovhconfig** tha should replace version of php from 5.4 => 5.5

```
; pour plus d'informations sur ce fichier:
; http://www.ovh.com/fr/g1175.format_du_point_ovhconfig

app.engine=php
app.engine.version=5.5
;apc.enabled = 1
http.firewall=none
environment=production
```